# Twilio call busy status

Tags: twilio, status

I am integrating twilio call. My requirement is when twilio call status is 'busy' an email will be sent to user. But I didn't receive the busy status. I received 'no-answer' as status on following cases.

1. Twilio makes a call and I cancel the phone.
2. Twilio makes a call when the phone is already in a call.

every time I received 'no-answer' status. Can anyone explain when I will receive 'busy' status?

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

You can use the `busy` property in the `status` parameter to determine the calls that meet this criteria. I'm not sure why in the second scenario, the caller would not be receiving a busy signal.

Here's an example in Python you could test with calling more than one number to determine if this might be a carrier issue. You can also read more about the status parameters [in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#call-status-values).

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID
auth_token  = YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of call objects with the status property busy
calls = client.calls.list(status="busy")
```

Comment: Ok. Twilio makes a call and I cancel it. After 10 seconds twilio makes another call. Can I have control this 10 seconds?

Comment: Control to do what exactly?